# Caliburn Micro - ActvateItem stops working when compiled on new dev pc

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I am having weird issue with small 32bit app that is using caliburn micro framework. When I compile it (successfully) on my new computer (win 7 pro 64bit, vs 2010 pro) it works until I want to change the view using ActivateItem. Then nothing wrong happens but the view is not changed. When I compile this on old pc (win 7 ent 32bit, vs 2010 pro) it works.

I know that this is not very clear "problem" but I wanted to check if anyone had some similar problem and I am really unable to describe it more properly.

Comment: What version of CM are you using? Latest? Worst case you can DL the source, build it and debug it, though I've not come across this issue myself and I've built on two machines with similar setup. It may still be a bug though, but I'm not sure how (don't think there are any architecture specific build/preprocessor directives in there)

Comment: latest &  i did the debugging (however, i have not mentioned it in my post)

during the debug i get "lost" in delegates around
CloseStrategy.Execute(new[] { ActiveItem }, (canClose, items) => {
                if(canClose)
                    ChangeActiveItem(item, true);
                else OnActivationProcessed(item, false);
            });
in Conductor.cs

Comment: When you say you get "lost", do you mean you are just confused as to what's going on or that you are hitting a lot of thread switches? Not sure what you mean there :) - though it can be a headache to debug if you are many ViewModels deep (due to the enumeration of the IGuardClose implementors etc)

Comment: i am probably getting closer to the end - right now i see that IsInitialized (in void IDeactivate.Deactivate(bool close) from screen.cs) property is false when compiled on my new pc whereas it is true (and i bet correctly) on my old one. i need to find the reason for this.

Comment: Could it be a race condition maybe?

Comment: it is really weird - when i set breakpoint on IsInitialized getter/setter it is set to true after the first view is opened but on the next get false is returned. and i am unable to find out why this is happening.

Comment: Maybe there's some private access to IsInitialised in some class - you'd expect it to break on the setter otherwise... v.strange. If I had time I'd have a look myself, just pressure at the moment for projects :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found major flaw in my code.

I had [Export(typeof(IShell))] attribute provided for one of mine in-app view models whereas it was supposed to be declared only for shell view model. Problem was then caused when GetInstance was called for IShell.

```
protected override object GetInstance(Type serviceType, string key)
    {
        string contract = string.IsNullOrEmpty(key) ? AttributedModelServices.GetContractName(serviceType) : key;
        var exports = container.GetExportedValues<object>(contract);

        if (exports.Count() > 0)
            return exports.First();

        throw new Exception(string.Format("Could not locate any instances of contract {0}.", contract));
    }
```

it has returned expected Shell view model when compiled on old pc but unexpected one when compiled elsewhere.